# nmake: Cross compile libcurl on windows (64-bit)

Tags: c++, curl, visual-studio-2015, libcurl, nmake

I'm having an issue building 64-bit libcurl w/ VC14.  I follow the instructions, but my install of VC14 is 32-bit (I cannot change this for the time being).  However, at least in the Ui, I can cross compile 64-bit.  The Makefile.vc and/or MakefileBuild.vc don't seem to allow me to easily designate the compiler, and it always ends up erroring out, telling me file.obj is x86 and I'm trying to compile x64, or something to that effect.

So, long story short, how can I tell nmake to use the 64-bit compiler?

Comment: in VC installation in the Start menu you have at least 2 shortcust - one for compiling x86 targets and one for compiling x64 targets. Make sure you are using the correct command line terminal to compile curl project. Also As I remember - curl has a readme explaining parameters for the compilation. You may need to modify the default settings  - but it seems to me the modifications were mostly to change output to static lib, use static runtime libraries etc...

Comment: The two I have in the start menu under Visual Studio 2015 -> Visual STudio Tools are "Developer Command Prompt for VS2015" and MSBuild Command Prompt for VS2015".  The former is what I've been using.  The latter does not recognize nmake.  I assume the batch file doesn't set the proper environment variables.

Comment: There should be following terminal link in the start menu "Visual Studio x64 Cross Tools Command Prompt" - If you say it is missing - check that your installation includes everything. Maybe you have not installed x64 compiling tools

Comment: Will do!  Cheers.